My client keeps changing password and denying me access before the project is fully complete. How do I politely ask him not to do so?
I have a nice but emotionally vulnerable client. I work towards developing his websites and his client's websites, and other kinds of project like graphic design, photo editing, etc.
When it comes to website development, I install the CMS and create a username and password for admin access, or back-end access. Then, the client requests the admin credentials, which I forward to him.
On several instances before, and now too, the client keeps changing his website back-end's password, denying me access to the back-end even before the project is completed and financially paid in full. This creates problem for me because I no longer have full admin access (for example, in WordPress CMS). Then what he does is, he takes over the whole CMS and sends me an invite to sign up for the website. This gets frustrating for me and creates more problem for me at work. I had told him before on several occasions that "please do not change password of back-end until the project is fully complete". But he tends to take everything personally and gets agitated when I tell him to do something he does not want to do. Over that, he takes over the whole back-end admin panel and starts playing with the website code and contents, sometimes complicating things further or messing up the website.
Now this is getting frustrating for me, and I am not so good at handling other people's emotional burden, especially my client (I don't think that is my job either - to deal with their emotions). I am also not getting paid for fixing problems that arise because he keeps playing with the code and contents of the website and messing them up. So, I just want to politely but firmly tell him not to change back-end user credentials and passwords until the project is fully completed and fully paid.
How do I deal with the client and tell him this? And how can I protect myself in the future if he damages the website before the project is complete (because he takes over the whole back-end admin panel and starts playing with the website code and contents)? That is also another concern that I have.
Please help.

I sure hope that you have secured payment for your work so far.

What prevents you from not giving the credentials until you have finished your work?

That client you mentioned above, Is it from freelance sites?

@jcaron I thought not to make him upset by not doing as he says (he asked for giving credentials and then changed it without asking me first). But I think you are right. It is creating more problems for me and I am being too nice with the wrong person :(

@JorgeLuiz Yes, I found him from a freelance site. I have been working for quite a long time with him on many projects. He doesn't pay terribly, but he is not very generous either.

@MichaelHarvey Do you think that I should ask for him to pay 100% in advance first, before starting any project? Considering that he likes to "take over"?

@JorgeLuiz He is also very fond of micro-managing which can sometimes get difficult and frustrating, kind of intrusive.

"I don't think that is my job either - to deal with their emotions." The clients easiest to land have a certain overlap with the clients easiest to lose (aka difficult clients). Welcome to freelancing where your job is to deal with everything because you have no boss to cover for something that isn't your job. Which is not to say that you shouldn't act as proposed in the answers, but forget the phrase "not my job".

Well said, @DonQuiKong. I couldn't agree more. Yes, don't agree to any future projects on the same terms. But yes, it's part of the job.

Thank you everyone. I feel that this thread will be really helpful for any freelancer who comes across such a challenge. Your contribution is truly appreciated.

I think the real solution is to eventually push back and stop taking this s--t. Being emotionally vulnerable (what does it mean even) is not an excuse from not being professional and wasting your time without paying. If he's emotionally vulnerable, then you become bulls--t vulnerable and fire him. That is, if you can afford that.


a nice but emotionally vulnerable client

Although you say that, the rest of your question and comments make him sound like the customer from Hell. I suggest that you ask yourself whether you need him as a client, and whether he is worth the energy he is costing you. If not I'd cut him loose.
If you feel that you need to keep going with this guy, i.e. you really need to money, I suggest you follow your own advice for this project.

From now on, I will create a super user account for myself and give him limited access until the project is complete.

For future work, I suggest that your draft your contract very carefully, making it clear

What the deliverables are;
What constitutes the evidence that the deliverable is complete;
What payment is due (include margin for dealing with client);
What the handover procedure is (e.g client can put his grubby fingerprints on once payment is made).

And, for your own sake, try to find clients who aren't pathological.
@Siva I worked for a successful multi-disciplinary engineering practice, which had invested a lot of time in proposal templates to cover contingencies. Out agreement contained a clause that made it clear that all the IP that we developed remained ours until all invoices were paid in full. That came in handy on at least one occasion. (Of course we had an NDA for their IP).
We developed on our platform, and handed them snapshots at agreed times.
We also had standard payment terms: typically the client would pay an upfront invoice, and we would invoice for work in progress so we never lost money if the client failed to pay. Project Leaders were empowered to stop a project until work had been paid for (as a last resort).

Thank you. It is very helpful that you have highlighted what I should be covering in our project agreement. I will also try to make sure that my client is not pathological, but it sometimes takes a long time to judge that. I can see where you are coming from, though, so perhaps when I become aware that a client is pathological, I should change my strategy of dealing with the client, or fire him entirely. Thank you so much for your advice.

It is interesting to hear about your experience. So, in case of web design or development, for smaller projects, is it fine to ask for an upfront payment and use a similar tactic that your team used?

@Shiva I suggest you think about managing risks. If I engage you to build a website, the happy case is where I get my website, you get your money, I get extra customers. Other businesses say "Let's get Shiva to build our website, such he did a great job for Simon". The worst cases end in tears: I don't get what I think I paid for, you don't get paid what you think you are owed, a 3rd parties sues both of us, etc. Think about how you will manage the risks so you and your client feel in control. Progress payments are a widely accepted tool. Maybe google "earned value"?

I always create a Super User account only for me, then other accounts (SU or lower) for other people. So, if we are two SU, I have my access and the other users can do whatever they want with their account and password.
If necessary, I limit other user's permissions so they don't mess up my work and my code.
Also in this way you separate users interactions with the CMS, i.e. you can see in the logs who did what.
I don't think you should explain anything to him, just act this way and tell him that this is the best practice to work on a project.

Your response is very helpful and truly appreciated. Thank you.

Yep - if you want me to run or build a system, I'm running or building that system. That means you can't make changes without my permission, and you certainly can't kick me off. And that you get promoted to the top user only once the project is complete, and you've paid in full. This also lets you take back the code, assuming a non technically adept user. You just back up and delete your work if they don't want to pay you.

"Best practices" is indeed limiting write access to source files to developers assigned to the project. One day that will be whoever else the client pays to maintain it (perhaps themselves), but for now, that's you. Also, everything should be in revision control. That way if someone does manage to play with things and mess a bunch of stuff up, its a simple matter of reverting the changes.

+1. The log part is crucial. Two users should never share an account because it is then impossible to attribute actions to a user, and in your case as a freelancer this could have significant legal implications (IANAL); you need to be able to show what you’ve done and more importantly what you haven’t done or a client ever accuses you of wrongdoing or on their system. The logs also document your delivery on the contract requirements to some degree (again IANAL).

From where can I manage logging all activities? Is there any platform that can help me in doing this in a unified place? Thank you for making me aware of the log part. I wasn't aware of the legal implications before. Thanks a lot.

@Shiva You may not have access to the logs but the platform will almost certainly keep them, and in case of litigation they could probably be requested through whatever legal means apply in relevant jurisdictions (again IANAL).

This is a client who wants to take over. Knowing that anything you do will be changed means that you are not in charge of the project once you have handed over control. What that means is that the project has to be structured in small pieces AND that you get paid in full for any piece that is done before handing over any master passwords. You do not "own" the project, the client does.
A "nice" client is one that pays you to fix up the mess they have made.
Accepting that this is how the client operates means that you don't have to worry about how the project looks, behaves, or functions. Simply do the changes requested, get paid, then hand over control.

The client doesn't pay me for fixing the mess that they have made. Instead, he creates a scene all the time and argues with me, quarreling with me about why I am not creating a complete new full admin account for him so that he can take over and make changes on the website from his end as well. It is hard to deal with him, and sometimes, that makes me angry. From now on, I will create a super user account for myself and give him limited access until the project is complete. Do you think that will be good idea? And how do I counter him if he keeps venting at me for not giving him admin access?

Today he yet again came in the way of my work. I told him not to touch a certain page in the website until I have finished my pending job on that page. BUT he added a lot of new contents on that page and that has again disrupted my work, because I can't finish the job in a way that I want. I am again having to wait until he responds to me which will again take time. I am not able to delete the page contents without asking him first. This is getting frustrating. How do I deal with him getting in the way of my work?

Unfortunately, a lot of clients don't know what they want until they see what you have created. Then, they want to make a lot of changes. He is adding a lot of work and time to the project. Simply charge him for the extra time. Remember, your job isn't to create a web site, it is to make the client happy while you get paid.

@Shiva You can revert his work - the work he wasn't cleared to do yet - and finish your own work as planned/promised. Then when he complains, tell them it's exactly what they are doing to you. You can work with them later to redo their changes if they're still relevant.

@sehe Ha ha. I will try that next time. This is clever.

You won't like my answer.
The reality is that when politeness, logic and reason ends (and it seems that have already happened in your case), you're down to more decisive means of exerting pressure. And these, in your position, should be the points written down in the contract you signed with the customer.
I learned it the hard way; I wrote my first freelance project before I even hit 18. I was in the secondary school and wrote an application for a pizza restaurant owner. I had virtually no contract at the moment of writing; we agreed on the scope of the task and I assured him that I will fix any errors that will surface after finishing the implementation.
And when I finally did finish the implementation, suddenly I started getting reports that "there is an error: lack of a button which does this and that". Luckily, that project finally ended and I got paid.
Before you start cooperation with any customer, prepare a contract, which states:

A very precise, easily verifiable definition of "done"
Tools, which will be used (yours or customer's)
Any additional obligations (such as purchase of additional libraries or tools)
Any specific restrains placed on you and the customer (this is where you can state that customer is not allowed to do any modifications to unfinished product)
The way you will get paid (for instance a part of payment for every finished part of the project - and don't move your finger until you get paid). This will at least allow you to minimize losses if customer quits in the middle
Easily verifiable conditions for paying fines by both sides in case of breaching of contract (e.g. finishing project after the deadline or interfering with the development process)
Any additional security measures against customer's possible wrongdoings.

If a customer refuses to sign a well written and honest (just to both sides) contract, it is a clear sign that you really don't want to do any work for such a person.
Having such contract in hand, you can exert pressure on the customer by warning that breach of contract has certain consequences. If customer decides to breach the contract, you can always open a case in the court. The latter is obviously an extremity you probably want to avoid, but is still an option. Civil contract has legal force and you can seek fulfilling points of the contract through a lawsuit. It depends though on the country you live in and its laws; for instance in Poland the losing party has to pay 100% of lawsuit costs (including even payment for the lawyer who was representing you), so if you have solid grounds for the lawsuit, the risk is minimal.
If you don't have such a contract right now, you can still exert pressure on the customer, but you need to weigh the risks. You risk that customer will cancel the contract and you won't get paid, but the customer risks that you won't do the job for them and that also might cause unpleasant consequences.
In your case I would probably create a separate super-user account, do not give the customer credentials to it and calmly explain that any changes made to the final website causes delays and unless you are paid for those delays, you can not allow for them to being made.
There's a technique for working with unreasonable people called "a broken record". Every time customer uses different arguments, you say calmly: "I understand that, but unless we renegotiate our contract to take into account all the changes being done by any 3rd parties, I can not agree to giving you credentials for superuser account until I finish my job". And then calmly repeat the same thing for every single argument that will be thrown at you.

What you wrote - "If a customer refuses to sign a well written and honest (just to both sides) contract, it is a clear sign that you really don't want to do any work for such a person."

This is what happened with me here. He wanted to keep friendly relations with me and was not comfortable to sign a contract. I was stupid and naive and didn't make a clear contract with him. The job was being done without any contracts because he did not like it, and he thought that it is interfering and making our "friendly relations" bitter. Shouldn't have allowed that :-(


And thank you so much for your response. This is incredibly helpful for me.

@Shiva, FYI - it may depend on the country you live in - oral agreement may also be treated as legally binding (again, this is the case in Poland). So if e.g. you make living out of freelance projects, and you feel that it is needed, you may also consider going to court with all the problems that you have with the customer. But think everything through and make your own decisions.

@Shiva, and don't be too harsh on yourself. You screwed up by not having a contract. I screwed up by not having a contract. A lot of people did the same in the beginning of their careers and a lot got screwed up in the process. It is the essence of saying "people learn on their mistakes". There's also a saying, "there is no place for sentiments in business". When money starts playing any role between people, their behavior may change to the level you wouldn't imagine. Keeping good relations is fine, but contract is a necessity. If someone doesn't want one - this is a solid red light.

@Shiva, if this customer's behavior is completely unacceptable for you, there's always an option to say: "Since it is obvious we can not agree on some things, I won't be doing any more work until we have a proper, signed contract". But - again - you have to weight risks. It wouldn't hurt to prepare such contract beforehand though.

@Shiva "He wanted to keep friendly relations with me and was not comfortable to sign a contract." Have you ever heard the saying, "good fences make good neighbours"?

@Shiva Simple, no contract? You do work, he can see. He pays you for work, he owns it and has access. He changes what you're about to work on, you re-quote for the next changes since the scope has changed. You start work, he loses access until it's finished and paid for. He wants access again? Pay for your changes/time and get updates, or revert to what it was, and with a new quote when he wants to go ahead with that or other changes to cover your time. He will either want smaller and frequent blocks of work or he'll quit the relationship. Better now than later.

"Easily verifiable conditions for paying fines...": be careful, as that may not be kosher in some jurisdictions. In Australia we were always careful to talk about "liquidated damages", which meant that one party would suffer a loss as the result of a potential action by the other, and the specified amount would be full compensation.

It may be too late to help with this specific client, but in general my recommendation would be to do all of your design and development work on a development platform that you control and only you can access, and then push that work to the client's own environment according to a schedule which you arrange.
Your development environment could be hosted on a service of your choice or could be run locally via docker containers or even just a virtual machine on your own computer. Because it's your private environment which the client doesn't pay for, he cannot demand access to it.
In the case of Wordpress, copying a site can be a bit clunky, but there are plugins and services which can make the process easier. Include the cost of these in your project budget.
Explain to the client that while he can make changes to his copy of the site, those changes will be overwritten when you publish the next round of updates, so he should avoid making significant permanent changes until the project is finished.
Give the client advance notice of when you will be publishing the next round of changes, and warn him each time that this will overwrite any changes he has made. If the client refuses to let you overwrite his changes with your work, then you can ask him to provide confirmation in writing that he doesn't want you to complete the project.
If there are changes he wants you to incorporate, you can have him provide those changes to you, and you can incorporate them in your development environment.
You can even arrange a meeting before each push where you review his changes and work with him to incorporate them into your copy. This is billable time, of course.
The client can be shown progress in your development environment either by giving him front-end only access or by screen sharing, but he cannot have back end access because it doesn't belong to him.

I see. So suppose I am working in his hosting server, do I not own the product (legally) until the client fully pays for the product, such as the website?
If I do own the product, then I can restrict the client's access even on his hosting server, isn't it so?

It really helps to have your own server. There are cheap hosting sites that you can use, show the client what you have built, get his feedback, and make the changes requested. Since it is your server and not his, he doesn't get to make any changes on it.

Whether or not you legally own the product until he pays for it is determined by the contract you're working under, what jurisdiction you're in, and so forth. But the goal of this approach isn't to establish ownership of the code, it's to maintain control over your work until it's ready to be provided to the customer.  By working directly on the customer's server, you're unable to prevent him from making changes. Legally, you can't stop him from changing his password because the hosting is in his name, regardless of who owns the rights to the code. Hosting your own eliminates that problem.

One good option for  inexpensive hosting is AWS Lightsail. You can get a small instance up and running in a few minutes for about 5USD per month. Also, the first three months for each instance are currently free.

@barbecue I see. Thank you so much for explaining this. It will add one more step, which is migration to his server after the job is done, but I get the point why it is always better to code the website on my own server. Thanks for your advice.

By copyright law, websites belong to the website developer, not the client, so I build them on my own hosted server (or I set up their own with their credit card but not tell them where it is or is hosted). I do not allow access to any client and set up the login urls with secret wording.
I take sites down, if they choose not to pay or stop paying a monthly maintenance fee or the initial build fee. I call that line item:
"Design Fee, the overall looks and layout of the website. This design is copyrighted by our company and is a recurring fee for as long as our designs are being utilized by _____. If payment is stopped, you will have to hire another developer to create a brand-new site, and the present site will be taken down within 90 days of non-payment. This is a commonsense reasoning that no person likes their own work that continues to have value to be taken over and paid to a competitor or not paid at all."
And my second line of contract/estimate is about the monthly maintenance fee and then a per page charge, etc.  And I always charge sales tax, since I do not sell websites, so it really is more like renting them most likely if ever audited by the state. (which I actually was and do not have to charge sales tax but the state at that point doesn't realize that retain ownership myself even if files are sent out of state onto other servers I rent from - I take no chances since I owed them $10,000 in back taxes and won the case, but it was scary and clients don't mind paying the tax.)
So anyway, that has been my business model for the past 16 years and I've never not gotten the contracts. Also, if they question it, just explain that clients do not normally know what they are doing and can make unbelievable messes, and it is in their best interest at my low fees to take advantage of the maintenance fee which allows them to ask for changes here and there for up to one hour of work per month.
By the way, since you are building websites for his clients, the temporary server idea is best until you can turn it over to them. They'll come back to you for a fee to fix things, I'm sure.
Also, I never have to write a contract or hire a lawyer as suggested.  It's all in the estimate and invoice. Paying anything on it, is the contract being accepted.

I feel like most of the rest of the answers are a little more surreptitious than  what ever worked for me. Creating superuser accounts and forcefully changing passwords can be surprising for clients, and surprises often lead to getting fired.
In this case it may be due to incompetence, but I've worked with clients who have processes to automatically change passwords due to regulatory compliance or just plain good security practices.
Make this part of your change process.
I assume you already have a contract, so work to amend it if necessary. Also make sure that there's a good general disclaimer in your future contracts. You want something like, "usual access."
That could and should cover a whole array of other situations that you're not thinking about right now, like what if they don't pay their Internet bill or if they decide to firewall you.
Once this is done, the next time that the client changes the password, inform them that it causes additional work on your part and that it's covered in this  usual access clause.
The next time it happens, manage it as a straight-up change request. It should be the same as if they asked you to change the website colors or use a new layout. You do already have a set process for managing changes, right?
The crux: they are causing you additional effort due to their actions. You are paid for your effort. Therefore, make it clear that this causes more effort and therefore more cost for them. It sounds like you're taking it personally, when really it's just a business matter.
Be prepared for them to continue to do this and pay your change cost. That's their choice to make.

I appreciate your inputs, but I think that if I follow your advice then I will have to keep making legal corrigendums and amendments all throughout my life, and there will be no end to it.
I think I was as much professional as I could get. And I am certain that you have no idea how such clients can be, and how much burden can dealing with them be. I am certain some of the "other responders" have perfectly answered my question. I have fired my pathological client today. The intense relief that I felt, thinking to be able to give more time to my other jobs, and my personal life, speaks enough.

@Shiva To be fair, allowing the customer admin access where they change the code is never "as professional as it gets", unless they're a partner web developer. There's a reason big companies work through issue trackers, separate OTAP environments and acceptance/test procedures. Yes, that's painful at times, but it sure avoids the more painful situations like the one you describe. A midway is always healthy, and apparently you will have to err more on the safe side.

@sehe You are absolutely right. It was my fault that I gave him access to the admin panel. In a professional environment, I should not have done this to keep myself on the safe and sane side. I guess I learnt it the hard way.

Legal amendments and change requests are needed when the contract is a fixed price contract. That is why I have decided not to take any fixed price contracts. Everything is hourly. That way, changes simply get rolled into the work and I can be responsive to what the client really wants. The project can continue as long as the client wants to keep paying. The day they stop paying is the day I stop working.

My advise is to send him a letter by email (with email acknowledge receipt ) as below
Subject: Important: Admin Access for Website Development
Dear Valuable Client,
I hope you’re doing well. I wanted to send you an important update regarding the website project and the admin access. Please read the message below and confirm receipt at your earliest convenience.
As we continue developing your website, I would like to kindly request that the admin credentials remain unchanged until the project is fully completed and payment has been processed. This will ensure that I have full access to finalize the website and address any necessary adjustments or issues.
Making changes to the back-end during development can result in delays and unexpected issues that might impact the website’s functionality. I’m dedicated to providing you with a high-quality final product, and keeping the access consistent will help us avoid any complications.
Once the project is fully completed and ready for launch, I will happily hand over full control of the admin panel. At that point, you’ll be able to manage the site as needed. In the meantime, I am happy to discuss any updates or changes you would like to make — I’m here to collaborate and ensure everything meets your expectations.
Please confirm receipt of this email and let me know if you have any questions or concerns. I appreciate your understanding and cooperation in this matter, and I look forward to bringing your vision to life.
Best regards,

Handling this situation requires a balance of professionalism and firmness, as well as some preventive measures to protect your work and avoid potential misunderstandings. Here are a few steps that could help:
1.  Set Clear Expectations in Writing: Draft a polite, straightforward email or message, perhaps saying something like:
“For the smooth completion of your project and to ensure everything is finalized as we discussed, it’s essential for me to retain back-end access until all development and design work is completed and fully paid. Changing the password before then can lead to issues that may delay the project or require extra work to fix. I would greatly appreciate your cooperation on this.”
2.  Include Terms in Contracts: If you don’t already have a contract, consider creating one for future projects, outlining a clause about administrative access and payment terms. You could add a clause stating that until the project is completed and payment is made, back-end access should remain unchanged, or an hourly rate will apply for fixing any issues caused by unauthorized changes.
3.  Use Temporary Accounts: When setting up CMS access, consider creating a temporary account with restricted permissions for the client’s review purposes, reserving full admin access for yourself. This way, they can see progress but can’t make changes that might disrupt your work.
4.  Implement Regular Check-Ins: For emotionally sensitive clients, having scheduled updates can reassure them about progress and possibly reduce their need to access the back-end preemptively.
5.  Document All Changes: If he does access the back-end and makes changes that cause issues, document these instances clearly. This provides a record in case there’s a need for clarification on what caused delays or additional work.
6.  Prepare a Polite Boundary Statement: In case he becomes emotional, you could respond with something neutral, like:
“I want this to be a positive experience for you and deliver a project you’re happy with. For that, keeping the back-end access unchanged is key. I’ll gladly provide full access upon completion and payment to ensure everything works smoothly.”

By addressing the issue directly but kindly and having safeguards in place, you can both protect your work and set a precedent for future projects.

Independent website designers and developers need to ensure they have a legally binding contract. Get yourself an attorney and an accountant. Make sure you write up unique contracts for every job. Do not accept the clients blanket contract. If you are on a call with the client and they have a lawyer on the call; you then reschedule the meeting so your attorney can be on the meeting to represent your interests.
One alternative is to setup a cloud instance during development. Do not give the client the backend admin passwords until you are done with the project. Specify this in the contract. Relinquish the passwords when the project is complete and the site has been moved to a production server.
A contract ensures you will be paid for the work performed even if the client cancels the project or eliminates the entire department using your software or if they go out of business suddenly. The contract can be used to enforce payment via legally binding agreements.
There is a video on YouTube which covers all this and the room was full of independent contract workers in your field. It's worth a listen as it's excellent advice.
Don't be afraid to fire problematic clients. It's not worth the headaches and frustration.
